# Como copiar matriz de inteiros para o tipo Mat em OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv

Gostaria de saber como copiar uma matriz de inteiros para um dado do tipo Mat do OpenCV ? 
A seguir segue um exemplo que criei para ilustrar o meu objetivo, que corresponde a uma dada matriz gerada pelo usuário ( variando de 0 ate 255 - variação de cor no OpenCV)  ser mostrada na tela em forma de cor através do `imshow`. Contudo o que está aparecendo na tela é um quadrado todo preto, ou seja, a copia não esta sendo bem executada uma vez que deveria aparecer uma faixa de cor branca, outra de cor preta e uma terceira de uma cor qualquer.

Ou seja, quero converter a matriz de inteiros para o respectivo tipo da matriz em OpenCV (Mat ) e mostra-la corretamente através do `imshow`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include "opencv2/videoio.hpp"
#include "opencv2/video/tracking.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


int main()
{

int image[128][128];
    // Zerando a matriz pra nao pegar lixo da memoria
    for(int i=0; i< 128 ;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<128 ; j++)
        {
            image[i][j]=0;
        }

    }
    // Colorindo a matriz
    for(int i=0; i< 128 ;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<128 ; j++)
        {
            if(i<40){
                image[i][j]=0;
            }
            if(i>40 && i<80){
                image[i][j]=255;
            }
             if(i>80 && i<128){
                image[i][j]=122;
            }
        }

    }
    // Criando matriz para mostrar para o usuario
    Mat Mostrar(128,128, CV_64FC4 );
    // Copiando a matriz original para a outra matriz
    for(int i=0; i< 128 ;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<128 ; j++)
        {
        Mostrar.at<int>(i,j)= image[i][j];
        }

    }
    // Exibindo a matriz em forma de cor para o usuario
    imshow("Exibindo", Mostrar);
    waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

**EDITADO :**

Na realidade(erro meu, não deixei claro ) estou tentando fazer isso pra uma imagem colorida mesmo. Segue o código que estou usando :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include "opencv2/videoio.hpp"
#include "opencv2/video/tracking.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
  // Abrindo uma imagem colorida
  Mat image = imread("C:\\Users\\imagem.png");

     int m[242][208];

  // Passando a imagem para a  matriz
     for(int i=0; i< 242 ;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<208 ; j++)
        {
          m[i][j]=  (int)image.at<uchar>(i,j);
        }

    }
     for(int i=0; i< 242 ;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<208 ; j++)
        {
        // Aqui farei algo com a imagem, passar algum filtro, etc
        }
    }
// Criando a matriz auxiliar
 Mat Mostrar(242,208,CV_64FC4 );
 for(int i=0; i< 242 ;i++)
 {
        for(int j=0; j<208 ; j++)
        {
            Mostrar.at<int>(i,j)= m[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
}


// Exibindo a imagem modificada
    imshow("Exibindo",Mostrar);
    waitKey();

    return 0;

}
```

Esse programa compila mas não funciona do jeito que deveria. Da forma que está ai deveria pelo menos mostrar a imagem original mas acho que eu estou fazendo algo errado ( não estou utilizando o número e tipo de cainais correto, etc).

Não sei se o que eu quero fazer da para fazer dessa forma ai mas o que eu quero é abrir uma imagem colorida  passar ela para uma matriz( normal mesmo sem ser do tipo Mat) trabalhar sobre essas matriz e mostrar o resultado para o usuário ( mas para isso tem que converter para tipo Mat).

Pois o meu objetivo é criar os métodos que irão modificar a imagem manualmente mesmo, para que se use o mínimo possível o OpenCV.

**EDITADO 2 :**

Agora está praticamente do jeito que eu quero mas está apresentando 2 erros :

No código abaixo eu estou pegando a imagem e extraindo cada canal dela e guardando em uma matriz para posteriormente trabalhar sobre esses canais. Contudo do jeito que esta o código( apenas para mostrar que a conversão deu certo pois ambas as imagens devem ser as mesmas) a saída modificada ( Mostrar ) está apresentando umas colunas pretas no final da imagem, ou seja, as ultimas colunas dessa matriz não estão iguais a da matriz original, mas eu não sei o que possa ser.

O segundo problema é se eu descomentar a linha :

```
 //   r[i][j] =30 ;
```

O código compila mas da erro de execução ( trava tudo ) o que teoricamente não era pra dar pois eu deveria modificar o valor caso eu queira.

**Há alguma maneira de concertar esses dois erros ?** Sem que modifique muito esse código pois eu quero essas partes bem definidas mesmo do jeito que está( pois meu objetivo é separar em funções , uma para gerar as matrizes, outras para modifica-las e uma para mostrar o resultado).

Segue o código :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include "opencv2/videoio.hpp"
#include "opencv2/video/tracking.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{

     Mat image = imread("C:\\Users\\imagem.png");
     int r[image.rows][image.cols],g[image.rows][image.cols],b[image.rows][image.cols];
     Vec3b  color = image.at<Vec3b>(Point(0,0)); // para inicializar

    // pegando cada canal de cor
     for(int i=0; i< image.rows ;i++)
     {
        for(int j=0; j<image.cols ; j++)
        {
          color = image.at<Vec3b>(Point(i,j));
          r[i][j]=  color[0];
          g[i][j]=  color[1];
          b[i][j]=  color[2];
        }

     }

     Mat Mostrar(image.rows,image.cols,image.type());

    // aqui seria para modificar os canais
    for(int i=0; i< image.rows ;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<image.cols ; j++)
        {
         //   r[i][j] =30 ;
        }

    }


    // Juntando novamente para poder mostrar
     for(int i=0; i< image.rows ;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<image.cols ; j++)
        {
           color[0] = r[i][j];
           color[1] = g[i][j];
           color[2] = b[i][j];
           Mostrar.at<Vec3b>(Point(i,j)) = color;
        }

    }


    imshow("Exibe original",image);
    imshow("Exibe modificada",Mostrar);
    waitKey();

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá, a questão é que você está tentando renderizar uma imagem em escala de cinza então o tipo de dado para a matriz não é **CV_64FC4**, mas **CV_8UC1** (8 bits sem sinal e 1 só canal).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include "opencv2/videoio.hpp"
#include "opencv2/video/tracking.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main() {

    int image[128][128];

    // Colorindo a matriz
    for(int i = 0; i < 128; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < 128; j++) {
            if(i < 40)
                image[i][j] = 0;
            if(i > 40 && i < 80)
                image[i][j] = 255;
            if(i > 80 && i < 128)
                image[i][j] = 122;
        }

    // Criando matriz para mostrar para o usuario
    Mat Mostrar(128, 128, CV_8UC1);

    // Copiando a matriz original para a nova matriz
    for(int i = 0; i < 128; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < 128; j++)
            Mostrar.at<uchar>(i, j) = image[i][j]; // Veja: <uchar>!

    // Exibindo a matriz em forma de cor para o usuario 
    imshow("Exibindo", Mostrar);
    waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

Isto vai exibir quase que uma bandeira da Estônia para o usuário.

---

**Resposta 2, após solicitação para imagem colorida**

Nesse caso em que você já vai carregar uma imagem pronta, não faz sentido ter as matrizes `m` e `Mostrar`, descarte-as. O próprio objeto `imagem` é a única coisa que você precisa. Você pode percorrê-lo e editá-lo diretamente.

Mas como agora a imagem é colorida, e as cores possuem 3 canais (*Red*, *Green*, *Blue*, ou 4 canais se contar o *Alpha*), você pode precisar da classe `Vec3b` para ajudar a armazenar os valores, senão pode acessar direto como neste exemplo: `image.at<Vec3b>(Point(x, y))[2] = 255`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include "opencv2/videoio.hpp"
#include "opencv2/video/tracking.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
    // Lendo uma imagem colorida via parâmetro
    Mat image = imread(argv[1]);
    // Poderia ser assim também
    // Mat image = imread("C:\\Users\\imagem.png");

    for(int y = 0; y < image.rows; y++)
      for(int x = 0; x < image.cols; x++) {
          // Obtém o valor do pixel
          Vec3b & color = image.at<Vec3b>(Point(x,y));

          // Faz algo com o pixel...
          // AMARELANDO A IMAGEM PIXEL A PIXEL
          color[0] = 30;
          // color[1] = ?;
          // color[2] = ?;  
       }

    // Exibindo a imagem modificada
    imshow("Exibindo", image);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

Se você precisa manter sempre a imagem original como referência, basta copiar ou carregar de novo em outra variável: `Mat img_original = imread(argv[1]);`.

Comment: Olá amigo, a sua resposta é quase o que eu quero mesmo. No entanto eu queria fazer isso para imagem colorida. PS : eu editei a pergunta para maior esclarecimento.

Comment: Favor verificar se atende após a resposta 2.

Comment: Olá, a sua resposta 2 ajudou muito. Mas ainda está apresentando 2 erros, que talvez sejam besteiras  que não estou percebendo, favor ver a pergunta editada ( EDITADO 2 ).

Comment: Eu não encontrei os erros que você relata no seu último código (copiei e colei direto no compilador). Obtive como resultado a exibição das duas imagens, uma original, outra amarelada (descomentei `r[i][j] = 30;`). Não tenho mais nada que possa acrescentar agora.

Comment: Olá amigo, consegui resolver o problema. Contudo, por você ter respondido a pergunta e solucionado praticamente todas as dúvidas eu atribui a recompensa você.